# How do I fix: Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: wordpress, web, analytics, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have been actively trying to redesign, increase page speeds and other things for my workplaces website. (Built by a previous employee using a custom Wordpress theme) I had been notified that this error has been starting to come up when testing our page speeds now. The scores we had been getting originally were appalling anyway so it's not really much of a surprise to me to be seeing errors haha.

[image]

Could this be because of broken links to google analytics? Or that The webpage is just so slow it wont test it?

Any information on this issue would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

while I was testing my site where I used self-signed SSL certificate, I got the error. I switched the site to http instead of https, then I got Lighthouse loading the page and showing score. Hope this helps someone.